# wp_get_current_user behavior seems to have changed when using outside normal loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Previously was experimenting with creating a php file included in the footer as a javascript via :

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
```

One of my goals was to do check if the user has a certain capability before rendering out this particular javascript file.

It was working...till a day or 2 ago...thinking it has to do with the recent wordpress update.

Previously I was attempting the following:

```
include('../../../wp-load.php');

if(current_user_can('administrator')) {
    //print out some javascript stuff
}
```

However now it doesn't work. And when attempting to see what the current user is via:

```
wp_get_current_user();
```

It is just an empty object.

Wondering if anybody has a clue to what was changed, and what I am missing to get this working again.

Thank you.

Comment: Just had a quick look at `app/wp-includes/user.php` which is reliant on the `global $current_user` varaible. If there's no logged in user, it returns user id 0

Comment: Agreed, but there is a logged in user. However if I print that user object to the console its empty. Before it wouldn't be. The cookies for a logged in user are still there when inspecting the page. I feel like something changed in wordpress to effect this that I am missing somehow.

Comment: you can test the connected user before to enqueue the JaavScript file. Moreover it's not recommanded to use a direct acces to a PHP file. it's better to use instead AJAX (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or REST (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

Comment: Why are you not using wp_enqueue_scripts to enqueue the script?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts